# Magento Category Thumbnail

Tags: magento, thumbnails, categories

I am trying to make use of the Magento Category thumbnail, but it is not working. I've followed many tutorials online (eg http://www.douglasradburn.co.uk/getting-category-thumbnail-images-with-magento/),
and all of them make mention of the function :

```
$_category->getThumbnail()
```

which is supposed to be in the Category model. I'm running Magento 1.6 and I can't find this function anywhere. I've also downloaded 1.5 and 1.7, looked in there and it is nowhere to be found. When I run the code it gives me no errors however, just nothing is output.

Here is my full code:

```
 <ul id="nav">
 <?php foreach ($this->getStoreCategories() as $_category): ?>
     <?php echo $_category->getThumbnail(); ?>  
     <?php echo $this->drawItem($_category) ?>
 <?php endforeach ?>
 </ul>
```

(I am trying to use the thumbnail as a menu item where it is present)

---

Got it working. The secret is you need to re-query for the FULL category data using this code:

```
Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->load($_category->getId())->getThumbnail()
```

I followed this tutorial somewhat:

http://www.h-o.nl/blog/using_category_images_in_your_magento_navigation/

for having category thumbnails in your menu.

thanks
T

Comment: Did you set the thumbnail correctly on the backend? There won't actually be a method getThumbnail(), this is a magic method. Also, post code.

Comment: Thanks for clarifying that, I thought there was something like that going on! I have triple checked that I have the thumbnail set. I've added the code to my original post.

Comment: Test that the foreach() is iterating. Also do a `Zend_Debug::dump($_category);exit;` and post the result.

Comment: It is iterating for sure because the categories get printed out. Zend_Debug doesn't work, but I already tried a print_r and the thumbnail attribute is there (id 124) but it's protected. I checked the database and the thumbnail img is in there in table catalog_category_entity_varchar. Is there any other setting I'm missing, like a visibility setting, or something obvious?

Comment: Also just cleared all my caches, re-indexed, etc.

Comment: When added to [category] view.phtml,
<?php echo $this->getCurrentCategory()->getThumbnail(); ?> 
works fine, but not under top.phtml. This means 
$helper = Mage::helper('catalog/category'); is not selecting the thumbnail..

Answer (score 11, accepted):

For what it's worth, your solution works but is quite inefficient.

Using:

```
Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->load($_category->getId())->getThumbnail()
```

will add a few hundredths, maybe even tenths of a second per category to your page's load time.

The reason for this is you've gone to the trouble of getting a model collection and getting the item within it, and then you'll be adding new database calls that fetch the full data for each category. You need to simply ensure you collect the full category data in the first place.

The reason what you had before wasn't working is because the category collection wasn't told what attributes it needs to select. It was in effect just returning flat data from the catalog_category_entity table, not joined with any attribute tables.

What you need to do is probably more along these lines:

```
<ul id="nav">
<?php foreach ($this->getStoreCategories()->addAttributeToSelect("*") as $_category): ?>
    <?php echo $_category->getThumbnail(); ?>  
    <?php echo $this->drawItem($_category) ?>
<?php endforeach ?>
</ul>
```

In fact, ideally you want to override the `->getStoreCategories()` function to add the wildcard filter.

I recommend opening `app/code/core/Mage/Eav/Model/Entity/Collection/Abstract.php` and learning what sort of very cool collection functions have been written. Mastering EAV Collections is like a rite of passage for Magento developers. Once you do this you'll be unstoppable!

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 4):

There is no need to change app/code/local/Mage/Catalog/Model/Category.php

It can be done easily through these line of code...try this...Its Works

```
$child= Mage::getSingleton('catalog/layer')->getCurrentCategory()->getId();

$imageSrc = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->load($child)->getThumbnail();

$ThumbnailUrl = Mage::getBaseUrl('media').'catalog/category/'.$imageSrc;

echo "<img src='{$ThumbnailUrl}' />";
```

Answer (score 2):

this worked for me:

```
<img src="http://etienneaigner.com/shop/media/catalog/category/
     <?php echo Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->load($_category->getId())->getThumbnail(); ?>"

     height="338px" width="338px"
     alt="<?php echo $this->htmlEscape($_category->getName()) ?>" />
```

Answer (score 1):

Just came across this answer. However, in later magento editions 1.7+ there is no need to add overheads to code, you can add more standard (and custom) eav attributes to the Category collection via config.xml. If you check the Mage/Catalog/etc/config.xml you will notice under the  node that there are nodes:

```
   <category>
        <collection>
            <attributes>
                <name/>
                <url_key/>
                <is_active/>
            </attributes>
        </collection>
    </category>
```

So you can create a module of your own and add more eav attributes:

```
    <category>
        <collection>
            <attributes>
                <thumbnail/>
                <image/>
            </attributes>
        </collection>
    </category>
```

And they will be added to your category collection.

Comment: Can you expand on your answer, the first set of nodes does not exist in the config.xml file. Quite obviously it needs to be added but where and how is it referenced once in place.  While I am sure your answer is correct and I'm sure YOU know how to use it but myself and I'm sure others do not.  Thanks.

Comment: This is the only correct answer for this. You should not load an entire category just to get the thumbnail image...